# Windows 10: Access is denied to non-existant file

Tags: windows-10, permissions, python, cmd.exe

This is a really strange problem, I can work around it but it really bothers me and I'd like to know what's happening here.

I'll start with the end result and then everything I did leading up to it, although I'm almost certain the culprit is python somehow:

```
$ move rolling_stone_50_best_songs_of_2017.csv rs.csv
Access is denied.
    0 file(s) moved.

>>> os.rename('r_s.csv', 'rs.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'r_s.csv' -> 'rs.csv'
```

[Explorer error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iggax.png)

I also get error messages with other commands (involving rs.csv), and vim can't write to it.

I am the only user and sole admin of this PC and this is on a local drive.
Doesn't matter if I'm an admin or not, and also doesn't matter if I use cmd, powershell, bash, python or explorer. the file rs.csv doesn't exist here (that I can see), it's definitely not a hidden file.

I created a file called rs.csv, I used the move command in cmd to rename another csv file. I opened a python 3.6.3 interpreter, also in cmd and was playing with the os and csv modules.

I wanted to find a way to use the cls command in the interpreter, and tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/518007/7024304

I hand typed the answer, and could've made a typo:

```
>>> cls = lambda: os.system('cls')
>>> cls()
```

After I did this python crapped out and my ConEmu tab closed. When I went back to the directory all the changes I made in there were gone. I'd downloaded and renamed several csv files as well as making a file called test.log or something similar, they were all missing. And for whatever reason rs.csv is the only problematic filename.

Yes I have restarted the computer. And the problem is persisting even after I have deleted the directory and remade it.

Any ideas? It's really frustrating

Comment: Most likely logical errors. Try checking the partition with the proper tools.

Comment: That worked :) . had further problems with the folder this happened in. ran chkdsk. And suddenly all is well.Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Michaelbay for the answer, seems it was a disk error. Running chkdsk fixed everything, even though it didn't find any problems according to it's logs.